# How do I install MATE desktop icons?

Tags: software-installation, icons, mate, icon-themes, desktop-icons

How do I install MATE desktop icons?

I have installed standard MATE from repositories on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system, this way:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop
```

at this point, the option to select MATE at the cog in the greeter did not appear, so I had to run

```
sudo apt install mate-session-manager
```

after which MATE did appear at the cog in the greeter. I have installed `mate-utils` because I could not make screenshots without it

```
sudo apt install mate-utils
```

Still, for many apps the icons are missing:

[image: MATE desktop with missing icons]]

How do I install the missing icons?

MATE version 1.12.1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install `ubuntu-mate-icon-themes`:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-icon-themes
```

That may provide most of the missing icons native to the Mate environment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This opinion is a bug in Ubuntu MATE 20, installs some themes and gets into everything. Only after defining the icons of the categories as Portuguese disappeared. I found this solution and it worked for me:

```
sudo sed -i '/Icon\[/d' /usr/share/mate/desktop-directories/*.directory
```

This is a temporary solution for broken icons on Ubuntu Mate 20. For more details see:

- [Menu icons not found on fresh new install 20.04](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/menu-icons-not-found-on-fresh-new-install-20-04/21579/12)
- [Bug report: lots of app icons are missing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1873466/)